# Is it possible to pause CloneZilla?

Tags: clonezilla

I've been running a clone on a drive with bad sectors for 7 hours. The external is getting hot to the touch. I'd rather not fry both drives, but I also don't want to start over. Google results came up with nothing.

Anyone know a way I can pause to give the drives a rest?

Comment: I dont think so...  Perhaps get a desk fan to blow on the drive?

Comment: I'll restart with DDrescue to copy good sectors first. At least that I can stop and continue. The drive is enclosed. Poor air flow.

Comment: "I put ice over it in the time being." Damn. Cook some eggs. (Joke aside, try to remove the case and make the drive function somehow?)

Answer (score 0):

Go to a terminal and send it a stop signal (`kill -SIGSTOP pid`), send a continue one when you want to resume (`kill -SIGCONT pid`)